# useState setter not updating state when called in useEffect

Tags: reactjs, use-state

Pretty much what it says on the title. When I console.log(repos) it returns an empty array. Why is the `repos` state not updating?

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

export default () => {
  const [repos, setRepos] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      try {
        let repo_lists = await axios.get(
          "https://api.github.com/users/Coddielam/repos"
          // { params: { sort: "created" } }
        );
        setRepos(repo_lists.data.slice(1).slice(-10));
        console.log(repo_lists.data.slice(1).slice(-10));
        console.log(repos);
      } catch (err) {
        setRepos([
          "Something went wrong while fetching GitHub Api./nPlease use the link below to view my git repos instead ",
        ]);
      }
    })();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="content">
      <h2>View my recent git repos:</h2>
      <ul>
        ...
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: The behavior of setting the state is asynchronous in nature so it will not immediately set the state.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answer is very simple. Your `useState` is updating .. believe me. The reason why you don't see it when you `console.log()` is because `SetRespos` is an asynchronous function.

Basically when you declare a function to update you `useState` value, react will use it as an `async` function

**EXAMPLE**

```
const [example, setExample] = useState('');

useEffect(() => {
  
  setExample('Hello');
  console.log('I'm coming first'); // This will be executed first
  console.log(example); // This will come after this

}, [])
```

The output will be :

```
  I'm coming first
  // Blank Line
```

But still your `useState` will update after this. If you want to see that do this :

```
 useEffect(() => {

  console.log(respose); // This will give you the value
}, [respos])
```

I'm using a separate `useEffect` to `console.log()` the value. In the `[]` (dependency array) we pass `respos` which simply means that the `useEffect` will run every time the value of `respos` changes.

Read more about `useStates and useEffects` in react's documentation

Answer (score 4):

State updates are async. You will only see them reflected on the next render. If you console log the state immediately after calling setState it will always log the current state, not the future state.

You can log the state in an effect every time it changes and you will see it changing:

```
useEffect(() => console.log(repos), [repos]);
```

This effect will be called after the state update has been applied.